# HTML Agility Pack & VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net, parsing, html-agility-pack

There's plenty of examples out there for other languages.  Are there any examples for vb.net?

Comment: It may be better if you posted the snippets that you are trying and maybe we can help you figure out why they do not seem to translating easily to vb.net

Answer (score 0):

They are the same objects, used in the same way (in the same way that the BCL classes are used across all .NET languages the way - `string.Format` works exactly the same in C#, F#, VB.NET etc...).

All you need to do is translate the C# to VB.NET. There are [online tools](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) that will do that for you.

Comment: I've tried many snippets and converting for the last few hours.  Maybe its a noob error.  I'm just trying to scrape a local html file and used the provided hap util to determine the correct xpath

Comment: @shaiss - perhaps the issue is with your XPath, not with examples being in C#.